# Linking two UITextView to scroll together if one is scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have two text views beside each other with multiple lines of text.

How can I make them both scroll together based on scrolling either one of them at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

second make both textViews delagates

```
  tv1.delegate = self  

  tv2.delegate = self
```

Implement

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)inScrollView {

    self.tv1.contentOffset = inScrollView.contentOffset;

    self.tv2.contentOffset = inScrollView.contentOffset;

}
```

Here is a demo [txView](https://github.com/ShKhan9/txView)

Edit

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *tv1;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *tv2;

    @end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.tv1.delegate = self;

     self.tv2.delegate = self;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)inScrollView {

    self.tv1.contentOffset = inScrollView.contentOffset;

    self.tv2.contentOffset = inScrollView.contentOffset;

}
```

Comment: The question is about Objective C, and your Swift code doesn't synchronize.

Comment: Could you please explain where should I implement the above codes?

Comment: Hi Khan. I tried to open but it says incompatible version. Could you please put the code here and how can I use it. Thanks a lot for your kind support

Comment: open files by any editor code only in viewController.h , .m

Comment: when I assign self.tv1.delegate = self ... it gives me the following error: /ViewController.m:40:30: Assigning to 'id<UITextViewDelegate> _Nullable' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const __strong'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165362/discussion-between-adeeb-and-sh-khan).